# What does "SciRant" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

The word "SciRant" was seen in Twitter hashtags. An example from Twitter is given here. 
[image: Example]

I see this word as the combination of Scientific and Rant.

Does it mean that the author of that post thought the findings from that research paper was unreliable, or that the author was just self-mocking about his comments.

Thanks!

Comment: Please give an example of it use, and have you looked up the word "rant" in a dictionary and compared that to the content of the tweet.

Comment: It sounds as if it could mean both.

Comment: Thanks for the source.  Can you tell us what you found when you looked up the noun "rant" in a dictionary?

Comment: "If you say that someone rants, you mean that they talk loudly or angrily, and exaggerate or say foolish things." ---from Collins

Comment: textually and conceptually ***flawed***, not floored. hashtags use abbreviations invented by the authors of tweets!! hashtags are not words...

Answer (score 1):

I think both of your options are right.

From the actual text of the tweet itself, we can infer that the tweet author believes the findings from that research paper are unreliable.

But in order to not appear too angry about it, he uses the hashtag as a winking acknowledgement that he is perhaps being a bit to angry, or uptight about it, and that he is aware how he might be sounding to people when they read his tweet.

Comment: I think your interpretations make sense!